# Google Chrome DevTools elements search not working

Tags: search, google-chrome-devtools, element

Since about a week ago, I haven't been able to search for elements or the contents of an element in Google Chrome DevTools. Did the latest Chrome update break this functionality or has something else changed that I should be aware of?

I first thought I had accidentally changed some of the DevTools settings, but now the same thing started happening on my other dev machine as well, so I think it must be a bug in the latest update?

Is it just me? :)

EDIT: After a few days of wondering what could be possible causing this.. it just started working again after I restarted my Win 7 machine. The simplest fix the best fix, huh?

On another note, if the error starts happening again, I'll need to dig deeper as what might cause it and file a bug if necessary.

For now, it works and I'm happy :)

No results in DevTools element search. Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a legit bug. Thanks for reporting it. It's being tracked here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426815

As of November, it's been fixed in tip of tree (Canary) and has been merged to the beta branch (39).

(Originally answered by [vsevik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428563/vsevik), an engineer who develops the DevTools, however the post was deleted by moderators.) :/

Comment: Looks like it happened again. Not only it doesn't show element on `right click`->`inspect` when chromedriver runs window, but also now search shows that it found something (quantity), but doesn't show where is it in the code.

Answer (score 7):

I solved that by disabling "**Adblock Plus**", it worked in 3 browsers I tried.

Comment: Worked for me as well by disabling adblock plus for that site. Thanks.

Comment: On a second try, it seems that if your debugger is paused in the code somewhere, then the search gets hang (doesn't complete). If you forward the debugger, the search completes.

Comment: My adblock has been disabled but I solved the problem by switching to **Incognito Mode**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, search wasn't working, because I couldn't see the page. When I clicked on the page, under the Sources tab, I got a blank page. What worked for me was refreshing the page in Chrome. After that, the code showed up in Developer Tools, and I was able to search the code. This seems to be a Chrome bug.